# Masking crsf token in java

Tags: java, spring-security, csrf, csrf-token

I am working on a project that's quite old written in java. External audit happened for the code and they pointed out two modifications needed to be done regarding CRSF token ie. to periodically rotate the token and not have the same token for whole session and mask the token as when using the burpsuite tool the token is visible. I found some ideas for rotating the token and working on it but didn't find any helpful information about masking the token. Can anyone help me with some ideas about how to mask the token. Just to clarify the it appears for some reports when being downloaded.

```
GET /xyz/testcontroller/begin?event=Y&CSRF_TOKEN=-653632r324354546432tret455364&id=3576632446475442342
Host: xyz.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=452455535455762565; FileDownload=null; JSESSIONID=452455535455762565;
 < other security parameters>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.5414.75 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
<some more parameters>
Referer: xxxxxx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
```

Any help will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: You have to send the CSRF token in request body not in your URL. The URL is logged in most applications.

Comment: yes I agree but there are quite a number of screen to fix and have to test. So wanted to check if can any easier method to mask the token instead for short term and later can fix with proper planning.